# Play framework - database table generator

Tags: java, playframework

I am new to Play framework. I am using play 1.2.4 and Postgres 9.1.1. Here is my code:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import play.db.jpa.Model;
import play.data.validation.MaxSize;
import play.data.validation.Required;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Required
    @MaxSize(20)
    public String name;
}
```

When I run my application, play framework automatically generates the 'user' table. The column `name` is defined as `character varying(255)` and not `character varying(20) NOT NULL` as I would expect.

```
Column | Type | Modifiers
-------------+------------------------+-----------
 id | bigint | not null
 name | character varying(255) |
```

Since I am using `validateAndSave()` method and I need both `@Required` and `@MaxSize` annotations to be present. I could have also used the `@Column(nullable=false, length=20)` annotation, which by itself does not work with play's `validateAndSave()` method , but in that case I would end up having “duplicating” annotations.

Answer (score 2):

The `@MaxSize` is a validation annotation, not a JPA annotation.

You need to use

```
@Column(length=20)
```